# Validation to make sure dates don't fall between or overlap existing ones

Tags: c#, validation, datetime

Basically I have an offer which has a valid from and valid to date.

For example: 01/02/2012 to 03/02/2012

When I add a new offer I need to valid to make sure this offer doesn't fall inside or overlap the existing offer above.

My current code for this is below:

```
// Obtain the current list of coupons associated to the retailer.
List<RetailerCoupon> retailerCoupons = PayPalInStore.Data.RetailerCoupon.Find(x => x.RetailerId == RetailerId).ToList();

// Loop through each coupon and see if the timeframe provided in the NEW coupon doesnt fall between any EZISTING coupon.
if (retailerCoupons != null)
{
    foreach (RetailerCoupon coupon in retailerCoupons)
    {
        DateTime retailerCouponValidFrom = coupon.DateValidFrom;
        DateTime retailerCouponValidTo = coupon.DateExpires;

        if (DateTime.Compare(retailerCouponValidFrom, ValidFrom) < 0 && DateTime.Compare(retailerCouponValidTo, ValidTo) > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (retailerCouponValidFrom == ValidFrom && retailerCouponValidTo == ValidTo.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

return result;
```

Although this doesn't work, can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? What the debugger says? Which variables/conditions do not behave as expected?

Comment: Please show all the relevant code... where do you declare the `result` variable?

Answer (score 0):

After you've decided whether the start and end dates are inclusive or exclusive, the usual way to detect an overlap is to compare *opposite* ends of the two ranges being considered.

You need to ask "Does range 1 *begin* before range 2 *ends*?", and "Does range 2 *begin* before range 1 *ends*?". If both of those questions are answered positively, you have an overlap.

I'm not clear from your current code whether the ends are inclusive or exclusive, so I won't attempt to post actual code.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't think `retailerCoupons` can be null.

2) Why using `DateTime.Compare(t1, t2) < 0` when you can write `t1 <= t2` which is far more readable?

3) If you want to test if two intervals do not overlap, test the following:

```
bool they_do_not_overlap = t1_end <= t2_start || t1_start >= t2_end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but an opportunity to talk about one of my favorite libraries: [TimePeriod](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) for .NET. Just reading the article will give you some hints about how to deal with your situation.

Answer (score 0):

How about, using linq

```
var overlaps=retailerCoupons.Any(c=> c.DateValidFrom <= ValidTo && c.DateExpires >= ValidFrom);
```

then

```
result= !overlaps;
```